# Equivalence of statements about a linear map

Tags: general-topology, analysis, continuity, normed-spaces

I need someone to help me solve the following exercise:

> Let $(X, \|\cdot\|_X)$ and $(Y, \|\cdot\|_Y)$ be normed vector spaces over a common field $\mathbb K$ $(\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C)$. For a **linear** map $A: X\to Y$, show that the following statements are equivalent:

a) $A$ is continuous
b) There is a $\xi \in X$, such that $A$ is continuous in $\xi$
c) $A$ is Lipschitz-continuous

Of course you have to use the properties of $A$ being a linear map, but I can't really see what I am supposed to do. Maybe someone can give me the solution.

Can someone help? Still didn't find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:
$$(x_n\to\xi\implies A(x_n)\to A(\xi))\implies(x_n\to x \implies A(x_n) = A(x_n-x+\xi+x-\xi) = A(x_n-x+\xi) + A(x-\xi)\to\cdots)$$
$A$ bounded in a neighbourhood of zero implies $A$ continuous in zero.